# Does IntelliSense sometimes miss out on some Framework Class properties or methods?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I came across a DbParameterCollection object, which should have an "Item" property inherited from IList, but IntelliSense does not show this object has the Item property. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.item.aspx):

> The C# language uses the this keyword
>   to define the indexers instead of
>   implementing the Item property. Visual
>   Basic implements Item as a default
>   property, which provides the same
>   indexing functionality.

In other words, it's a C# syntax thing. Just use `list[index]` instead of `list.Item(index)` and you're set.

Comment: Ok, how do you know by looking at IntelliSense, if this class/object actually support this property? You'd very likely to miss out.

Comment: I believe it shows up as the `[]` operator in C# Intellisense, at least in VS2010... Should be at the top of the property list.

Comment: Hi, I have checked a few times and could not find [] in IntelliSense in VS2010 Express. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: Care to edit your question and post a screenshot? I've confirmed this in VS2010 Pro (did so while writing the comment above, in fact). Which VS Express product are you using? C#? Web? VB? It's possible the Intellisense package in those editions is different, but I'd expect C# Express, at least, to match what I've got...

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the syntax for using the "Item" property (VB) or indexer (C#) is a bit different from the syntax for "normal" properties.

In VB.NET, you would access an item in an IList like this:

```
myCollection(index) = someValue
```

In C# it looks like this:

```
myCollection[index] = someValue;
```